# My SQL updates lead to an index space allocation error because filegroup is full - Yet I know that my updates won't impact indexes

Tags: sql-server

I'm updating a json column called `JsonChanges` on thousand of rows of a table called `ObjetEvents`.

I have an indexed computed column based defined as:

```
builder.Entity<ObjetEvent>().Property(o => o.EnvoiId).HasComputedColumnSql("CAST(JSON_VALUE(JsonChanges,'$.EnvoiId') as bigint)");
```

I get an error:

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.ObjetEvents'.'IX_ObjetEvents_EnvoiId' in database 'MyDbdev' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

The thing is I only update a part of the json that doesn't affect `EnvoiId`.

How can I tell it to SQL Server so it doesn't update the index?

Comment: I somewhat doubt you have a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` that is only on one column and doesn't at least `INCLUDE` something (as that would be somewhat pointless) and if the index `'IX_ObjetEvents_EnvoiId` is a `CLUSTERED INDEX` then it will `INCLUDE` your JSON column (as it includes every column in the table).

Comment: you're right it makes sense, tks. Make it an answer.

Comment: So are you saying that the index `IX_ObjetEvents_EnvoiId` is a `CLUSTERED INDEX` or it has an `INCLUDE` on your JSON column? My comment at the moment is more an "educated" guess, which I dislike putting as answers.

Comment: Actually I replied too fast as after checking it is a non clustered index without any includes. I created it as I use `EnvoiId` in `where` clauses. While including other columns would surely be benefical for some queries, I wasn't under the impression it was pointless without any. I'll look into it. Meanwhile my question is still relevant then.